# Simple html dom parser can`t parse all page

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I need to get info from the center column of  [that site](http://vashmagazin.ua/cat/catalog/?rub=100&subrub=1)

(I need phone numbers exactly)

I`m using SimpleHTML dom parser, and was trying some curl method, but it always gives me html source without that central column !

I understood that using this code:

```
 $html = file_get_html('http://vashmagazin.ua/cat/catalog/?rub=100&subrub=1');
 $str = $html->Save();
 echo $str;
```

I need to say can i do this or not today or i will loose this order.
Sorry for my bad english, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pay attention on request headers and iconv for the charset conversion.

If you don't convert the string from windows-1251 in utf-8, preg_match will fail.

After conversion I used a simple regular expression to extract the phone numbers from the whole page.

```
<?php

    $url = 'http://vashmagazin.ua/cat/catalog/?rub=100&subrub=1';

    $ch = curl_init();
    $request_headers = array
        (
            "Accept" => "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
            "Accept-Charset" => "windows-1251,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3",
        );

    $header = array();
    foreach ($request_headers as $key => $value)
        $header[] = "{$key}: {$value}";

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.63 Safari/535.7');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $html = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $html = iconv("windows-1251", "UTF-8", $html);

    $matches = array();
    $pattern = '/\([0-9]{3}\)[0-9]{3,}\-[0-9]+/us';

    if (preg_match_all($pattern, $html, $matches))
    {
        var_dump($matches);
    }

?>
```

The source code above is fully tested and fully working.

If you can't install the curl library try to replace the curl block with a file_get_contents($url).

To install curl on your operating system search on google, on Ubuntu use **sudo apt-get install curl libcurl3 php5-curl** and restart apache.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in F:\xampp\htdocs\mag\index.php on line 5 --- maybe i need some library to include ? (except simple html dom that i already included)

Comment: You must install the curl library, in ubuntu you can install it with this command: sudo apt-get install curl libcurl3 php5-curl (otherwise, you can try to use directly file_get_contents($url)... The code is tested and works at 100%